# Style the standard modal window with css?

Tags: css, styles, modal-dialog

Is there a way to style with css the default browser modal window ( http://www.mysticcoders.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/javaScriptWindow.PNG.png )

I will be very greatfull if someone could help me.

Thanks. Cheers. Alex

Comment: You have to create a alert box which can be styled with the help of css...default window modal box can not be styled cox it is generated by the operating software

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to style this window. It is handled by the OS, not the browser and not the code withing the browser. If you want your own styled window, you'll have to use your own div based alert box.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot change the style of your default `Browser Modal Window` since they are developed by Some Programming Language and not by HTML,CSS or Javascript.

Look every browser like Mozilla Firefox,Chrome,Opera have thier own design for modal window.

But you can create your own modal window and use that in your site.